# Database migrations using mikro orm

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, database-schema

I have my current data base in POSTGRES AWS RDS and I am using Nest.js for backend also  Mikro-ORM for ORM also I have some pre define schemas along with there tables in database now I have made some changes to my schemas and I also want same to be reflected in my tables as well but at the same time I don't want to hamper my previous data how can I to it

I try to use migrations in Mikro-ORM but unable to implement it

Comment: You haven't provided enough info for someone to be able to help you. How did you try to implement migrations, and what issues did you encounter? Please include code samples if possible.